# Simulator for MHEG

Tags: simulator

Where do i get the simulator for MHEG?how to write,compile and run the MHEG application in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of high quality [MHEG-5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHEG-5) commercial products and several open source ones. I'm only going to list the open source projects here.

- [triton](http://www.oceanbluesoftware.com/products-amp-services/products/triton-authoring-tool) is an open source WYSIWYG compiler and emulator from Ocean Blue Software
- [openmheg](http://code.google.com/p/openmheg/) is a windows emulator that can run MHEG from a TV capture card.
- [mhegenc](http://code.google.com/p/mhegenc/) Has a compiler and decompiler that converts between text format and ASN.1 DER format ready for transmission by [broadcasters that support MHEG-5](http://www.impala.org/deployments)
- [mheg+](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mhegplus/) and it's [wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/mhegplus/index.php?title=Main_Page). It has macro expansion and named variables that makes code far more readable, it also has an emulator that can run files from disk or play a recording from a TV capture card. Written in Java so it runs under Windows or Linux.
- You can emulate MHEG from a TV capture card using [red button](http://redbutton.sourceforge.net/) in Linux. It also has a compiler and decompiler.

You can compile MHEG code in eclipse for any of these.